# R.java cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem

Newbie Alert:  while working on my android application my program was acting kind of buggy so i went to project, and did "clean." i reimported my R but for some reason all my other classes and xml files are giving me errors  "Cannot be Resolved or is not a Field"

i've restarted my eclipse and refreshed and im still getting these errors.  Help please!

Comment: Do you have "Build Automatically" ticked under the Project menu?

Comment: what do you mean by "i reimported my R", it should be crated automatically

Comment: try to save all of your works one by one and compile them again. maybe it will help you

Comment: is was created automatically but when i scrolled over one of the items it gave me the option import R. so i organized imports, and yes build automatically is checked

Comment: Did you import `android.R` by accident? Your resources are in `your.packagename.R`.

Comment: I figured it out I kind of backtracked and deleted "import android.R;"  I dont know why that happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me a lot as well. I found that it was usually a problem in one of my xml layout files such as missing a closing carrot or something like that. Just double check your xml's to make sure that you didn't forget something.

Answer (score 1):

I come across this error often as well. Here's how to fix it:

1. Check your xml layout files for any errors. Fix any you find.
2. Delete all the "import" statements on the .java files that has all the "cannot be resolved or is not a field" errors.
3. Clean. (Project -> Clean...)
4. Re-import needed packages (Source -> Organize Imports) (Control + Shift + O). If a dialog pops up, choose carefully!
5. Save.

Basically you need to have < your package name >.R imported if you are using layout files.
If you have recently renamed a package, that could have caused this. Fix all the import statements so that they import the correct R, < your package name >.R

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and i realized I have imported the wrong R.

Way to fix this,

1. Delete the already Imported R
2. Press Ctr + Shift + O and choose the R.
3. Save
4. Repeat the process and choose another R if it still has error.